# Have header take up entire width of body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a header and I need it to take up the entire width of the body. I have tried `width: 100%;` on the header `div` but there was still white space on both sides. I tried moving it to the left and making the width more than 100% but all that did was add a horizontal scroll bar and if you scrolled to the right, it would still have white space on the right.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
      <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="">
      <div id="nav">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    left: -9px;
    bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px; 
    background: url(images/dark_dotted.png);
    width: 105%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 4px orange solid;
}

#header #logo {
    padding-right: 700px;   
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;   
    font-size: 28px;
    right: -300px;
    font-family: roboto;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have margin:0; and padding:0?

Comment: Actually in chrome I don't see any white space at all on either side.

Comment: Try scrolling to the right.

Comment: I see it now, as in my answer, I debugged it a bit and it's your nav that is stretching to 1.3k pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Reset your css for body like this

```
body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

This will remove that white space from both side of your div

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that your `<div id="nav">` has that `right: -300px;` on it (presumably to counteract the `text-align: center;` on the header. Not knowing your site's requirements, I might suggest doing it this way:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header {
    background: url("images/dark_dotted.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid orange;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#header #logo {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 0 0 100px;
}
#nav {
    float: right;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 90px 30px 0 0;
}
```

This makes use of floats to position your divs, but does require that the height of the header be specified, as floats are taken out of consideration when calculating the sizes of their containers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your div of id nav.

It has a width of > 1k pixels, far off the side of the page.

You should try (on your nav):

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
```

More info:

My browser's calculated css for the nav ID:

```
bottom: 30px;
display: block;
font-family: roboto;
font-size: 28px;
height: 37px;
position: relative;
right: -300px;
text-align: center;
width: 1326.140625px;
```

As you can see width is off the charts; try assigning a fixed value of 100% to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

That will make everything fit into the viewport (as long as content doesn't extend it with absolute positioning, negative margins).

You have a large amount of padding on items (700 on the logo). Consider removing these or making them much smaller.

Header width needs to be 100%;

It's best to use static (default) positioning and control with padding and margins instead of trying to move it around by pixels and relative positioning.

Home
            About
            Gallery
            Contact

CSS:

```
#header {
background: url(images/dark_dotted.png);
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 4px orange solid;
}

#nav {
position: relative;
bottom: 30px;   
font-size: 28px;
float:right;
font-family: roboto; //this should be extended.. 'Robosto', serif (or appropriate type)
}
```

This assumes you aren't using `align="center"` an your html. You can center horizontally with `margin:auto` more efficiently.